# Collect all values from the variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`var collectionsd` returns in console log like

```
[5.2140564, 52.3705452]
[5.2180339, 52.3363171]
[5.2424313, 52.3595914]
[5.2739435, 52.388464]
[5.2368864, 52.336711]
```

In frontend shows only `[5.2368864, 52.336711]` I need to like below in JavaScript.

```
var collectionsd = [[5.2140564, 52.3705452],[5.2180339, 52.3363171],[5.2424313, 52.3595914],[5.2739435, 52.388464],[5.2368864, 52.336711]];
```

Update:-1

```
this.variables = JSON.parse(jso);
    this.passing=[];
    zc.passing.push(zc.variables['geo']);
    console.log(zc.passing);
ouptut:-
[5.2140564, 52.3705452]
[5.2180339, 52.3363171]
[5.2424313, 52.3595914]
[5.2739435, 52.388464]
[5.2368864, 52.336711]
```

I need to make the zc. passing values in single array.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: var collectionsd = zc.variables['geo'];

Comment: it returns new object. need to return same object with an array

Comment: What do you need as output ?

Comment: Please create a snippet with your code that reproduces the issue, and try to better explain what is the desired output... it is not very clear from your question

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "in frontend"???

Comment: Actually the data from json. value.

Comment: @JohnS Please be clearer. What is the input and what is the output ?

Comment: the variable output is multiple object with same variable. need to join the whole object with single varibale is possible?

Comment: @JohnS Please ask a colleague or friend to help you writing a well-formed  question. You are totally not clear

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. you can do it like this.

```
    var fruits = [[5.2140564, 52.3705452],[5.2180339, 52.3363171]];    


    fruits.push([5.2424313, 52.3595914] , [5.2739435, 52.388464] ,[5.2368864, 52.336711]);
    console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: var fruits not like u said. it s like
var fruits = [5.2140564, 52.3705452] [5.2180339, 52.3363171]

Comment: you want one array of all other arrays like [5.2140564, 52.3705452]? or you need 5 different arrays?

Comment: @JohnS `var fruits = [5.2140564, 52.3705452] [5.2180339, 52.3363171]` is not correct ! This is either one array or multiple variables

Comment: i knew but the json object return like that

Comment: @JohnS Which JSON object ? Your question is only showing us arrays

Comment: @JohnS please clear us you want an array , json or string?

Comment: i want an array in one same array

Comment: so you want an array with all resulted values?

Comment: try 
this.passing.push(zc.variables['geo']);

instead of 
zc.passing.push(zc.variables['geo']); and then console.log(this.passing);